# Angular JS: Toggle Only One Item at a Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I've got an list of names that I'm doing an `ng-repeat` on, and I've got an `ng-click` on each name, that when clicked, reveals a tooltip. I'm doing this like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in names" ng-click="tooltip = !tooltip">
  <span>{{ person }}</span>
  <div class="tooltip" ng-show="tooltip">This is {{ person }}'s tooltip</div>
</li>
```

When you click on a person 1's name their tooltip appears, but when you click on person 2, their tooltip also appears. I would like only one tooltip to appear at once. Is this possible using the toggle technique `tooltip = !tooltip` above?

I've set up a JS Bin of my issue, here: https://jsbin.com/faxoviwuze/1/edit?html,js,output

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$index`:

```
<ul ng-init="model.tooltip=-1">
<li ng-repeat="person in names" ng-click="model.tooltip = $index">
  <span>{{ person }}</span>
  <div class="tooltip" ng-show="model.tooltip==$index">This is {{ person }}'s tooltip</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I recommend to not use scalar scope variables like `tooltip`.
It's easy to unbind. Use something like `model.tooltip`.

[Simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/RtN4Y/14/)

---

Also, there is not a reason for `$scope` injecting - you can to use `controllerAs` syntax.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wegujihaqe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Just tested your code and it's not doing what is asked in OP